How to know which words are encoded with unknown tokens in HuggingFace BertTokenizer?
I use the following code to count how many % of words are encoded to unknown tokens.
paragraph_chinese = '...' # It is a long paragraph from a text file.
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, BertTokenizer
tokenizer_bart = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("fnlp/bart-base-chinese")
encoded_chinese_bart = tokenizer_bart.encode(paragraph_chinese)
unk_token_id_bart = tokenizer_bart.convert_tokens_to_ids(["[UNK]"])
len_paragraph_chinese   = len(paragraph_chinese)

unk_token_cnt_chinese_bart   = encoded_chinese_bart.count(unk_token_id_bart[0])
print("BART Unknown Token count in Chinese Paragraph:", unk_token_cnt_chinese_bart, "(" + str(unk_token_cnt_chinese_bart * 100 / len_paragraph_chinese) + "%)")
print(type(tokenizer_bart))

which prints:
BART Unknown Token count in Chinese Paragraph: 1 (0.015938795027095953%)
<class 'transformers.models.bert.tokenization_bert.BertTokenizer'>

My question is: I noticed there is one unknown token. How can I know which word causes this unknown token?
p.s. I tried print(encoded_chinese_bart), but it is a list of Token IDs.
Using transformers 4.28.1

When you use the BertTokenizerFast instead of the "slow" version, you will get a BatchEncoding object that gives you access to several convenient methods that allow you to map a token back to the original string.
The following code uses the token_to_chars method:
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast

# just an example
paragraph_chinese = '马云 Kočka 祖籍浙江省嵊县 Kočka 现嵊州市' 

tokenizer_bart = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("fnlp/bart-base-chinese")
encoded_chinese_bart = tokenizer_bart(paragraph_chinese)
unk_token_id_bart = tokenizer_bart.unk_token_id
len_paragraph_chinese   = len(paragraph_chinese)

unk_token_cnt_chinese_bart   = encoded_chinese_bart.input_ids.count(unk_token_id_bart)
print(f'BART Unknown Token count in Chinese Paragraph: {unk_token_cnt_chinese_bart} ({unk_token_cnt_chinese_bart * 100 / len_paragraph_chinese}%)')

#find all indices
unk_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(encoded_chinese_bart.input_ids) if x == unk_token_id_bart]
for unk_i in unk_indices:
  start, stop = encoded_chinese_bart.token_to_chars(unk_i)
  print(f"At {start}:{stop}: {paragraph_chinese[start:stop]}")

Original:
BART Unknown Token count in Chinese Paragraph: 2 (7.407407407407407%)
At 3:8: Kočka
At 17:22: Kočka


It would be great if the values are not hardcoded.

@Raptor I updated my answer with variables.

Based on answer from cronoik I wrote my own implementation of langchain_text_splitter.TokenTextSplitter for tranformers.BertTokenizerFast. It uses original text directly keeping unknown words (does not replace them with [UNK]).

from typing import Any

from langchain_text_splitters import TextSplitter
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast
from transformers.tokenization_utils_base import VERY_LARGE_INTEGER


class CustomTokenTextSplitter(TextSplitter):
    """Splitting text to tokens using model tokenizer."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        tokenizer: BertTokenizerFast,
        chunk_size: int,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> None:
        """Create a new TextSplitter."""
        super().__init__(**kwargs, chunk_size=chunk_size)

        self.tokenizer = tokenizer

    def split_text(self, text: str) -> list[str]:
        return split_text_on_tokens(
            text=text, chunk_size=self._chunk_size, chunk_overlap=self._chunk_overlap, tokenizer=self.tokenizer
        )


def split_text_on_tokens(*, text: str, chunk_size: int, chunk_overlap: int, tokenizer: BertTokenizerFast):
    """Split incoming text and return chunks using tokenizer."""
    splits = []
    tokenization = tokenizer(text, add_special_tokens=False, truncation=False, max_length=VERY_LARGE_INTEGER)
    input_ids = tokenization["input_ids"]
    assert len(tokenization.encodings) <= 1, "Should be Only one encoding"
    encodings = tokenization.encodings[0]
    start_idx = 0
    cur_idx = min(start_idx + chunk_size, len(input_ids))

    while start_idx < len(input_ids):
        start, _ = encodings.token_to_chars(start_idx)
        _, end = encodings.token_to_chars(cur_idx - 1)
        splits.append(text[start:end])
        if cur_idx == len(input_ids):
            break
        start_idx += chunk_size - chunk_overlap
        cur_idx = min(start_idx + chunk_size, len(input_ids))

    return splits

